# C# run SQL server query and not wait for result

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2012, task-parallel-library, executenonquery

I'm using [Serenity C#](https://serenity.is/) to develop a website.

When I click on a button it should run a SQL command, which starts a stored procedure.

My code

```cs
public ListResponse<MyRow> RunSQL(IDbConnection connection, ListRequest request)
{
    string sql = "EXEC SP_A @Username='" + Authorization.UserDefinition.Username + "'";
    SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(connection, sql);
    return new MyRepository().List(connection, request);
}
```

This code works fine, but it makes my web slow because my web needs to wait for the query to finish.

I want to kick off the SQL command and not wait for the result. Can I use the Task Parallel Library (TPL) for this?

Comment: You need background processing in ASP.Net. See the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: Watch out: Injecting values directly into a sql command string may lead to sql-injection issues

Comment: please *please please* look into parameters; if your `SqlHelper` doesn't allow you to use parameters: **burn it with fire**, and replace it with something that does (just saying: Dapper works fine: `connection.Execute("SP_A", new { Authorization.UserDefinition.Username }, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);` )

Comment: Because query takes a long time, I don't want my website is time out and waiting. Can you help me solve my problem?

Comment: Yes, write the API so that it dos not wait until the query is finished. It times out because you wrote it like that - and acutally it times out because you do not bother to change the timeout value from the default.

Comment: Are you sure it is `SP_A` that is taking such a long time, or getting that `MyRepository().List(...)` ? I expect you need the result of that List to build your response

Comment: @Hans Keﬆing: I am learning develop website, so i not good :( Can you show me code better than?

Answer (score 1):

> Can I use TPL (Task Parallel Library)??

No, you can not. You execute ONE statement, I am not even sure where you get the idea that paralellism of one item will do anything. if that query takes a long time, analyze whether it is defective. if it is not defective...

...change the API to be async an return a come back later with a token. It is waiting for the return value because you degiend the API to be synchroneous . you this is not acceptable, then the API is a design error and the design at least of this method should change.

Nothing in async/await/paralellism will change the API design and it will not magically make the request finish faster.

Comment: Because query takes a long time, I don't want my website is time out and waiting. Can you help me solve my problem?